# Bash: select all filenames with a ' Tb ' in the filename

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I'm trying to loop through a directory of image files and select only filenames with [space]Tb[space] in the name.

this: joe Tb joe.JPG

not this: bob_Tb_bob.JPG

Here's what I've got, which doesn't work.

```
files=* Tb *.JPG
    
for f in $files
do

#do stuff here

done
```

thanks for any help!

Comment: `for f in *' Tb '*.jpg; do` -- why create a `files` variable at all?

Comment: If the goal is to store _the resulting list of files_ when your script starts (instead of only evaluating the glob when your `for` loop is invoked), use an array for that. `files=( *' Tb '*.jpg ); for f in "${files[@]}"; do ...`

Comment: Alternately, if you want to parameterize the `Tb` part, assign _just that_ to a variable. `mid=Tb; for f in *" $mid "*.JPG; do ...`

Comment: Thanks Charles.  the first suggestion worked great.